# convert 2d floor plan image into 3d in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I have an image of a floor plan. such as follows,
[image]

what i want to do after this is, rotate the image in z axis and increase the length of black lines in the image in z axis, such that it looks 3d.
I have done this using following code,

```
im = imread('F:\floorplan.jpg');
i = rgb2gray(im);

peak = roicolor(i,0,1);
i = 10 + peak;
surf(i)
hold on
imagesc(i)
```

But after this i am getting the output like,

[image]

I think whats gpoing wrong is the function  `*roicolor*` (since it blackens the part which does not come under roicolor ie. from intensity 0 to 1, and rest part is white but in my case entire picture is turning out to be black).

what am i doing wrong? and is there any other way of doing this?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`surf(i, 'edgecolor','none')`

the surf plot has too many black lines to see the actual color!

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked... But somehow  it's coming in purple color. Is there any way of viewing it in original color?

Comment: @YaseefSheikh you will need to start playing with colormaps, but you are messing with them a bit by doing the +10. Try `colormap(gray)` to start with, but it may not be enough.